# is there a way to set a members limit on a redis sorted set?

Tags: redis

Say I want to store the 10 most recent additions to a redis sorted set where the 11th addition pushes the 1st off the list.  And until it reaches 10 items it just grows normally.

Do I have to check the length on each addition myself and delete the 1st element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you need to check the length, but have to cap it yourself:

`ZREMRANGEBYRANK [KEY] 0 -10`

Comment: To keep the 10 highest scored values in the zset as the OP asked, you'd need to use `0 -11` since Redis ranges are inclusive.

Comment: i am assuming that you are gonna run this everytime if you add items one by one, a lua script would work better no?

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to remove first member into ZSet
you can use this command :

```
ZREMRANGEBYRANK key 0 0
```

you can also sort 11th element as first member in ZSet using ZADD with score 1 :

```
ZADD key 1 member
```

EX:

> redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1 one
>   (integer) 1
>   redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1 two
>   (integer) 1
>   redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset 0 -1 withscores
>   1) "one"
>   2) "1"
>   3) "two"
>   4) "1"
>   redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREMRANGEBYRANK myzset 0 0
>   (integer) 1
>   redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1 three
>   (integer) 1
>   redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset 0 -1 withscores
>   1) "three"
>   2) "1"
>   3) "two"
>   4) "1"